# Digit and (Digit) are different!

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

A, B, C and D are four different single digit numbers.

---

It is given that:
A + B = D
A - B = C

It is also given that:
A × B = (B)
C × CD = (D)

---

Questions:

- **Decode why B and D are enclosed in brackets.**
- **Using that logic, explain how (A) and (C) are related to Stephen Herek and Steven Soderbergh respectively.**

Comment: Thanks for the puzzle! Lots of fun.

Comment: @isaacg My pleasure! That's the main reason we all love creating and solving puzzles right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A, B, C, and D stand for the digits

> 5, 2, 3, 7

The "(digit)" notation stands for

> Converting the digit to binary, then interpreting the binary as a base ten number.

Thus we find that

> 5+2 = 7
>  5-2 = 3
>  5×2 = 10 = (2)
>  3×37 = 111 = (7)

(A) and (C) are therefore

> (5) = 101, and Stephen Herek directed "101 Dalmations", and
>  (3) = 11, and Steven Soderbergh directed "Ocean's Eleven".

I solved this puzzle by

> Working in reverse. I looked up the filmography of the two directors, noticed they were both known for films with numbers in the title, and figured it out from there.

Comment: Excellent! You have made use of all the clues well..

Comment: I found the numbers, but since Soderbergh also have ocean twelve and ocean thirteen I couldn't go past it, haha. good job.